# Can the MacBook warn me if power adapter is not plugged?

Tags: macos, battery, macbook

Almost always I have my MacBook plugged to preserve battery health. But sometimes I forget to plug the adaptor or the wall outlet is switched off by others.

How can I have the MacBook warn me when it's running in battery mode?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I thought keeping a battery fully charged was _bad_ for its health?

Comment: @mashuptwice just googled, found nothing helpful

Comment: @user1686 MacOS would likely keep it at about 80% automatically.

Comment: What did you Google? Tell us what research you have done so that we are not wasting our time telling you things you've already tried and rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I have the MacBook warn me when it's running in battery mode?

Here are a few possibilities:

1. **Power cable connected/disconnected alerts**

> Open Terminal and run the following command.
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool true; open /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app &
> ```
>
> **Connect, or disconnect the power cable from your Mac and you will hear
> an audio alert**. There will be no visual/desktop alert telling you what
> the sound means.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [How to get a power cable connected/disconnected alert on macOS](https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/get-power-cable-connected-disconnected-alert-on-macos/)

2. **UnPlugged Application**

> UnPlugged is an application that **notifies you when the power cord of
> the MacBook is unplugged** or plugged back in. It also notifies you in
> regular steps about your batteries capacity while you run on battery
> or while you charge your battery.
>
> Notifications are done using the Notification Center, Growl or with a
> built in notification window.
>
> UnPlugged stays completely invisible while monitoring your power plug.
> Only a small Menu Item is visible, showing the current battery status.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

It costs $5.99.

Source: [Download UnPlugged for Mac | MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21158/unplugged)

3. **Juice Application**

> Use Juice! to keep an eye on your MacBook’s battery charge level. It
> can let you know when it’s time to plug in or when it’s OK to
> disconnect from the mains. **Set it to warn you** when you’re running low
> on battery or **when the power supply to your laptop is interrupted**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

It costs £2.99 / 3,49€

Source: [Juice! - The power monitoring app that looks after your MacBook battery.](https://ettoresoftware.store/mac-apps/juice/)

Disclaimer: I don't own a MacBook so I've not tested any of these possibilities.

---

#### Further reading:

- [Receive notification for power cord on/off in OSX Cocoa for the laptop - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788386/receive-notification-for-power-cord-on-off-in-osx-cocoa-for-the-laptop)